# Append data read from a file onto a bash array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops

I have a file, "thefiles.txt", just the output of an "ls -l" command.  I am interested in processing the first several timestamps.  I can get them from

```
> head thefiles.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 9
16:19
16:20
16:21
16:22
16:24
16:25
16:26
16:27
16:28
16:29
```

Now, what I really want to do is put them into a bash array that I'll call `tms`:

```
> declare -a tms
> head thefiles.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 9 | while read next_line
do
echo $next_line
tms+=($next_line)
done
```

The output from the `echo` command looks promising:

```
16:19
16:20
16:21
16:22
16:24
16:25
16:26
16:27
16:28
16:29
```

But none of the values ever get into `tms`:

```
> echo ${tms[@]}
(blank line)
```

I have tried a few variations such as

```
tms+=(next_line)
tms+=(${next_line[@]})
```

Anyone know how to make this work?  If you've got a completely different better approach, I wouldn't mind hearing that either.  (Still, for  my own edification, I would like to figure this problem out.)

Comment: Way more efficient than a loop: `readarray -t tms < <(head thefiles.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 9)`

Comment: @shawn   Thanks for the tip!  readarray looks very useful.  Learn something new ever' day!